# Radio Button - Initial Check and Click Check

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few radio buttons that I'm adding a class to which on click applies a highlighted background to the item label.

Right now I have it working where if people click on the radio it highlights that label. I would like it to be highlighted on page load as well.

Is there any way to highlight the label on page load if that radio is selected?

```
$('.subscription-option input').click(function() {
    $('label').removeClass("highlight-this");
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('highlight-this');
    } 
});
```

Page: https://www.solonutrition.com/product/dark-chocolate-mandarin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a different approach:

```js
var paintLabel = function paintLabel()
{
  $('label').removeClass("highlight-this");
  $('input:checked').parent().addClass('highlight-this');
};

$('input').click(paintLabel);

paintLabel();
```

```css
.highlight-this {
  background-color: #aa0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="rdb"> Rdb1
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="rdb" checked="checked"> Rdb2
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="rdb"> Rdb3
</label>
```

Comment: That didn't break anything, but it didn't appear to work either. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: For some reason let = paintLabel was causing an error, so I changed it to var and VIOLA! Thank you kindly for your help sorting this!!

Comment: @BirdieGolden that's strange but ok, glad to help!